# How to compare children of an element in a DOM with jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am working on a project where I have to be able to know that an element have repeated children .For example in that DOM, I want to know that the element `tbody` has similar children

[image: Example of DOM]

My goal is to extract data- and store it in a database -from pages that I ignore their structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jquery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) to get your td elements and iterate with [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) over them.

Comment: Please see the comment I added

Answer (score 0):

you can use [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/) for this. its very easy to use as well

for example you want to get all `td` tag in within your document:

```
String html=... //your html string
Document doc = JSoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select("tbody").select("td");
System.out.println(elements.size()); //prints number of td within tbody REGARDLESS of where in the DOM tree they live.
```

**Edit1:**

to get all elements you can do:

```
for(Element e : doc.getAllElements){
  System.out.println(e.getTagName());//prints the tag name
}
```

Comment: Thank you , but in that case I know that I have an element called tbody , in my project I will have to parse almost 100 pages so I won't be able to know the elements before , it depends on the page itself .

Comment: @user200099 u don't have to check for `tbody` specifically, you can just search for `td`, if you aren't looking for specific tag you can just select `everything`

Comment: This is my question how can I select everything ? and then compare the children of every element ?